# How can I elide top level index in functional amend

Tags: kdb, q-lang

```
.[string 10#.z.d;(til 10;4 7);:;"-"]
```

Does what I want; it replaces char 4 and 7 for each element in a list of dates with "-".

I seem to remember it being possible to elide the top level index (i.e. `til 10`) in some way. I would expect the below to work, but it doesn't:

```
.[string 10#.z.d;(0N;4 7);:;"-"]
```

How can I elide the top level index in dot-amend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q).[string 10#.z.d;(::;4 7);:;"-"]
"2014-04-22"
"2014-04-22"
"2014-04-22"
"2014-04-22"
"2014-04-22"
"2014-04-22"
"2014-04-22"
"2014-04-22"
"2014-04-22"
"2014-04-22"
```

Same behaviour as when indexing lists:

```
q)l:1 2 3
q)l[::]
1 2 3
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Didn't realise the null had to be generic.
The difference to `[]` indexing is that there, you can elide by just missing out the argument. e.g. `l[;42]` is enough, you don't need `l[::;42]`